# I have a problem with blending the background with lighting to make it look solid

Tags: lighting

[image]

Hi, there!

The highlighted area on the image is the problem here. According to my camera angle, the background needs to cover the angle vertically. So I've extruded the edge and used a bevel with multiple segments to make it look smooth.

I've used area/sun lights to see if it looks solid. But it seems to be highlighting the area where I've used bevel. I hoped to make it look solid background as if there's no difference. I've explored some possible solutions such as setting the lights around or adjusting the angle/size. But it's not enough.

By the way, I'm rendering on Eevee engine because Cycles is too noisy.

Comment: hello please share your file

Comment: It's probably your plane's topology see this: https://imgur.com/a/p9AB30E , but you need to give more information, add more images your meshes and settings

Comment: Hi. You should write an informative title that reflects the content of your question. Tell us what the problem is as well. A picture should only illustrate and support, explain your actual question and you should not skip the main part of describing your problem. Also, be specific. If you have tried some solutions, name them specifically and explain how and why they did not work. See: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: I did downvote the question and also voted to close it as I think it needs details and clarity. Don't take this personally, I just think it is really not formed well as it is now and also it's not useful at all for BSE platform since it has no text that could be used to find it using search engines by people facing similar issues in the future. I think the actual question is a good question and it would be great if it was formed well. And you would also get good answers for it. I think it's worth editing it to make it better.

Comment: Hi, there. I'm sorry that I'm being vague because I'm unsure how to address it. Let's say I'm trying to create a background that should cover up the camera radius and look solid. I've made it by using edit mode>edge select and used bevel with multiple segments to make it look smooth. But the bevel area looks brighter and highlighted when I set the lights. I want it to look like as if it is a solid background, no difference in between.

Comment: Does it look like the image I shared on the comment above? Also, add your comments to you question using the edit button, it's better for your question

Comment: Ah, yes! That's what I was talking about. The second one looks solid while the first one highlights some areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subdivision modifier instead of the bevel in order to make your plane smooth, and add some cuts close to the border to keep the shape as close as possible.

[image]

Comment: https://imgur.com/UmuQzuL, it worked.

Comment: Nicely done :)...